# Pandas SUM value by Index

Tags: python, pandas, sum, conditional-statements

How to sum all values from rows by string condition?

Original DF:

| schema | numb |
| --- | --- |
| tbc_hh | 1751732 |
| tbc_hh | 1084173 |
| tbc_rr | 1751732 |
| tbc_rr | 1084173 |
| tbc_zz | 1751732 |
| tbc_zz | 1084173 |

DF expect to get:

| schema | numb |
| --- | --- |
| tbc_hh | 1751732 |
| tbc_hh | 1084173 |
| tbc_hh_total | 2835905 |
| tbc_rr | 1751733 |
| tbc_rr | 1084174 |
| tbc_rr_sum | 2835907 |
| tbc_zz | 1751734 |
| tbc_zz | 1084175 |
| tbc_zz_sum | 2835909 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```py
out = (df.groupby('schema', as_index=False)
       .apply(lambda g: pd.concat([g,
                                   pd.DataFrame([[g.name+'_total', g['numb'].sum()]],
                                                columns=g.columns)]))
       .reset_index(drop=True))
```

```
print(out)

         schema     numb
0        tbc_hh  1751732
1        tbc_hh  1084173
2  tbc_hh_total  2835905
3        tbc_rr  1751732
4        tbc_rr  1084173
5  tbc_rr_total  2835905
6        tbc_zz  1751732
7        tbc_zz  1084173
8  tbc_zz_total  2835905
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
    df.merge(
        df.groupby('schema',as_index=False).sum().assign(
            schema=df['schema'].map('{}_total'.format)),
        how = 'outer'
    ).sort_values('schema')
```

output:

```
         schema     numb
0        tbc_hh  1751732
1        tbc_hh  1084173
6  tbc_hh_total  2835905
2        tbc_rr  1751732
3        tbc_rr  1084173
7  tbc_rr_total  2835905
4        tbc_zz  1751732
5        tbc_zz  1084173
8  tbc_zz_total  2835905
```

Comment: @Alvaro, just curious if this solution worked for you?